# Reference for approximation algorithms

Tags: algorithms, approximation

what is the best book to gain an introductory understanding of approximation algorithms? I'm looking for something along the lines of the [Sedgewick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032157351X), that has examples written in a well known language and not psuedocode.

Comment: Approximation algorithms is a theoretical topic. When it comes to practice, one uses heuristic algorithms.

Comment: Best is too subjective.  Subjective questions are not a good fit for this site; see http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  What are your criteria?  And what research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show your research in the question.

Comment: Try Vazirani's book, or Williamson-Shmoys.

Comment: Most books on approximation algorithms are designed for people who work in theory. Cormen leiserson rivest and Stein's introduction to algorithms' sections on approximation algorithms may be useful, but they use pseudocode.